# Can't route to "/login" with flask?

Tags: python, url, flask

When I type `/login` as url,it will go wrong

For example:

```
from flask import Flask ,url_for,render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login')
def index():
  return "index"

if __name__== "__main__":
  app.run()
```

The error turn out to be like this:

```
Not Found.
The requested URL was not found on the server.
```

When I replace `/login` with `/login/` or any other words like `/log` , it will be all right. How does that happen?

Comment: running your example and accessing http://127.0.0.1:5000/login works just fine for me... what shows on your console?

Comment: "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server.

If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: That's what appears on your browser, right? How about the log? something like: `127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2013 11:46:47] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2013 20:11:21] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"/" after "login" is automatically added. It's just after "login" that "/" will be added.I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read the [flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) **Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior**, [URL canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) and [Trailing slash in URLs - which style is preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-is-preferred)

Comment: But why it automatically replace "/login" with "/login/"? And then the browser will not find the page.

Comment: Please read flask quickstart  Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior part,  it has explained the reason why flask do this way.

Comment: For you given code, I can access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login`,it will not redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/`; and when I try to acess `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/`, it report 404 error. It is in line with Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior.

Comment: It's all right now. "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/" was recorded in the browser.So when I type"http://127.0.0.1:5000/login" , it will add "/". It's the brower that troubles me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

You could [turn off the strict url mode](http://librelist.com/browser//flask/2013/6/19/turn-off-strict-slashes-on-all-routes/#20a1f846adfe935671b5ffda4ce8f36a) in the route module, to get the `/login/` request working

Add the following code after you  `app = Flask(__name__)` and before you define any routing.

```
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

## Original Answer

My chrome is messing the request somehow. I open the `<F12>` developer tools and find that it automatically redirect my `/login` request to `/login/`.

```
General
Request URL:http://roxma.org:8000/hello
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 MOVED PERMANENTLY (from disk cache)
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:1080

Request
Content-Length:263
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 28 Dec 2016 14:24:44 GMT
Location:http://roxma.org:8000/hello/
Server:Werkzeug/0.11.11 Python/3.5.1
```

This is awkward. I don't know how to fix this issue. I guess the best solution is to use `/login/` style instead.