# Flask import not registering route

Tags: python, flask

```
flask-app 
 |_  app.py
 |_  views.py
 |_  models.py
 |_  resources.py
```

~ app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import views, models, resources


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

~ views.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    home = "<h1>Welcome</h1>"
    return home
```

For some reason I get a 404 not found error when I try to access localhost:5000.

Read this answer ([Can't route to "/login" with flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956656/cant-route-to-login-with-flask)) but I doubt it has anything to do with trailing slashes.

When I paste the route back into app.py it starts working again. Why is this? How can I fix my flask app? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having [issues with circular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112600)

You should use [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#my-first-blueprint)

Working example for you:

---

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import views, models, resources

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views.simple_page)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

simple_page = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__)

@simple_page.route('/')
def index():
    home = "<h1>Welcome</h1>"
    return home
```

---

This is also much a nicer pattern because now all your imports are at the top [as they should be](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: Thank you, I have refactored all my code to use Blueprints (http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/). You are right, much nicer pattern, thank you for your help.