# Is there any clear difference in url path with the path closed with slash or not?

Tags: url, web, path, tornado

The title question I met is when I runned a hello-world example with `tornado`
like this:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=9999, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = self.get_argument('greeting', 'Hello')
        self.write(greeting + ', friendly user!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/hello", IndexHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And I runned this code and runned the command like this:
`curl http://localhost:9999/hello`, it got 200 HTTP status.

But when I runned the command closing the path with slash:
`curl http://localhost:9999/hello/`,it got 404 HTTP status.

I know the problem in code maybe is this line:

```
app =  tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/hello", IndexHandler)])
```

So I want to know if there is an easy way to fix it with `http://localhost:9999/hello` and `http://localhost:9999/hello/` both accessed.

And I also really want to understand the difference in url path with the path closed with slash(/) or not, like the above `http://localhost:9999/hello` and `http://localhost:9999/hello/` or sometimes when we `put` the file.

Answer (score 4):

- Route path is a regex, so you can set it to `r'/hello/?'`, and it will accept both trailing slash and no slash.
- About a URL style, there's another question on SO which I just found with a search, sorted by votes: [When should I use a trailing slash in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-is-preferred)

Comment: Note that while this is valid regex, and will do what you expect in regards to pattern matching, it WILL mess up URL reversing (the output of `reverse_url()` will include the trailing `?`). I found this answer while Googling to solve this reverse URL problem. :)