# Change Permalink Settings

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Is it ok to have custom Permalink Settings in wordpress of http://www.sitename.com/sample-post instead of http://www.sitename.com/sample-post/. Is it ok with search engine.

ie, /%postname% instead of /%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

From Search Engine point of view the URLs with or without slash are two different identities and neither is preferred. From users point of view, we should have only one URL to avoid any confusion and better user experience. From SEO point of view, the preferred version should return 200 and the duplicate URL should 301 to the preferred URL

Matt Cutts (head of Google’s Webspam team) prefer trailing slash.

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/

You can also read more from here:

[When should I use a trailing slash in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-is-preferred)

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.sg/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Comment: thanks, Answers are too long as given is discussion but url-canonicalization is very important, but what i get that only trailing slash does not matter as long as other parameters are ok.