# Get parameter variables in a permalink

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I've a page that shows the last 10 articles of a database, and, with the `$_GET['show-all']` variable, it shows all the articles.

Now, I want to use permalink. For the 'standard' page, the permalink is

```
/articles
```

for the second one, I might use this

```
/articles/show-all
```

But search engines as Google recognizes it as another page, and generated a duplicated meta-tag error. So I want to use this permalink instead

```
/articles/?show-all
```

But all my attempts didn't work. I tried this code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/?(.*)$ /3/contents.php?p=articles&$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^articles/\?(.*)$ /3/contents.php?p=articles&$1 [L]
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: @moonwave99 I just edited the post with the rewriterule I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the canonical tag

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

to avoid "duplicate content" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to always use a trailing slash or not.

Since /name != /name/

Therefore go for /name?param in your case.

this topic has a lot of information about it by the way:
[When should I use a trailing slash in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-is-preferred)