# Differences between webservice URL ending with '/'

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I just started learning Webservices using JAX-RS in Java. My webservice URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/test/testWebservcie
```

That is working fine. Just to play around with it I added '/' at end of the URL like below

```
http://localhost:8080/test/testWebservcie/
```

even that is working fine and no issues at all. What is the differences between those two ? can I replace one with another ?

Comment: there's no practical difference, unless the server's coders were particularly anal and insist on one or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trailing slash in URLs - which style is preferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659). It makes e.g. a difference if you want to `java.net.URI("http://localhost:8080/test/testWebservcie/").resolve("foo")`: `testWebservcie/` is handled as directory so you'll get `http://localhost:8080/test/testWebservcie/foo`. Without trailing slash `testWebservcie` is not handled as directory so you are resolving against `/test/` and the result is `http://localhost:8080/test/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is none.

This is usually true of extensions as well, for example, the project I am on has us posting to a .json url. Personally, I think that is stupid and removed the .json and it works fine.

***HOWEVER***
If the coder on the server side was a stickler, he could code it in such a way that only one is valid.

TL;DL
They are the same unless someone has gone out of their way to make them not.