# Appending / at the end of the URL renders the same page?

Tags: spring-mvc, url

Consider the snippet:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/spitter")
public class SpittrController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm() {

        return "registerForm";
    }
}
```

where ***registerForm.jsp*** is as simple as this:

```
<form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Whn I type the following ***URL*** in my web browser:

> http://localhost:8080/web/spitter/***register***

I see this below page, which is fine, as per the functionality:

[image]

Now if I slightly modified the ***URL***, and do something like this

> http://localhost:8080/web/spitter/***register/***

then also the ***same page*** is rendered,

[image]

Why? Even though the entered ***address(URL)*** is not pointing to that ***request mapped in the controller***.

Any suggestions?

***EDIT:***

The whole problem arises when I have to work with Spring Security.

Consider the snippet:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spitter/")
            .authenticated().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/register")
            .authenticated();
    }
```

Now, when the user enters this in his browser,

> http://localhost:8080/web/spitter/***register***

he is redirected to the login page to authenticate himself, while

> http://localhost:8080/web/spitter/***register/***

doesn't redirects him to the login page, which is a security lapse.
 and I have to make this entry to

> antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/***register/***").authenticated()

in addition to

> antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/register").authenticated()

Is there any cure of this to get rid of it or else it will double the effort just to append the ***/*** just to redirect to the login page?

Comment: Can you provide your Web.xml code also ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445016/545127

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trailing slash in URLs - which style is preferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-is-preferred)

Comment: @VA31: Not using a web.xml. Configuration is done through Annotations provided by Spring-MVC for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
/spitter/register/**
```