# Go http Request detecting POST as GET

Tags: go

I am very new to Go, infact started today. But have run into a weird and frustrating problem. Simply put, the following code prints `r.Method` as GET when I make a POST request via POSTMAN.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "routes"
)

func cartHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf(r.Method);
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        cart.GetHandler(w,r)
    } else if r.Method == "POST" {
        cart.PostHandler(w,r)
    }
    //fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.Method)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/cart/", cartHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8010", nil)
}
```

The request being made is fine because a similar piece of code in nodejs detects it as a POST request.

Comment: Thanks Riscie, curl -X POST worked for me too. But still, POSTMAN should work as well, not sure if you use it, but I find it pretty handy.

Comment: So I just tested it with POSTMAN (the chrome extension) and it detects my POSTs as POST and GETs as GET. Not sure what is going wrong there...

Comment: I think I know whats wrong here. Did you enter the complete url into POSTMAN? including the last slash? Because if I don't enter the last slash, my POST is discovered as GET as well....

Comment: That was it... so frustrating, but that shouldn't have mattered right?

Comment: Well I am not quite sure what POSTMAN does but actually, the request shouldn't even get to your handlefunc. If I do the same test with curl, the request ends in the nirvana, which is what I would expect, because we don't have a route for /cart, only for /cart/

Comment: Ok. Anyways, thanks for figuring this out.

Comment: Btw. Here is a discussion about wether to use trailing slashes or not in URLs. Might be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/trailing-slash-in-urls-which-style-to-use

Comment: Probably a prefetch of sorts. Like how chrome will GET `/favicon.ico` for a domain.

Comment: Could be @thwd. However it seems like not the right thing to do in a tool specially designed for testing http backends...

Comment: fwiw: I asked about this within the POSTMAN project over at github. If someone likes to know more about why this happens... https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1687

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your HandleFunc remove the last trailing slash

```
    http.HandleFunc("/cart", cartHandler)
```

instead of

```
    http.HandleFunc("/cart/", cartHandler)
```

Or if you want your URL like that, enter it with the slash in POSTMAN and it should work like expected.