# How to include Less correctly

Tags: html, css, less

I'm having a small problem with Less . I can't seem to get it working. I'm running it client side. It just doesn't create the CSS, the page stays unstyled.

**Header**

```
   <!-- Include LESS Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/includes/style/general.less" />

    <!-- Include Scripts and Co -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

**Index**

```
    <body>

    </body>
```

**general.less**

```
@rcmsblue: #8AE9FD;

body{
  background-color: @rcmsblue;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably it's the absolute path in your `href` attribute. If your `includes` folder is in the same place as your HTML, try removing the leading slash in your include: `href="includes/style/general.less"`

Comment: does your less file load correct with the paths?

Comment: @JordiNebot Thanks, this did the trick.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have doubts about using relative or absolute paths/urls, read this [great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/1534704) by @PeeHaa

Answer (score 0):

Questioner might get the solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url) is a good info on slash rules. Few other points to consider when use LESS:

- Include your stylesheets before the script and when you link more
  than one, each of them compiled independently so any variables,
  mixins or namespaces defined in a stylesheet are not accessible in
  others. Detailed usage information available at
  http://lesscss.org/usage/
- And, don't forget to add MIME type that are associated content types served as static files by the web server.

  ```
  File name extension: .less
  MIME type: text/css
  ```