# Browser resolves relative urls as if they were absolute

Tags: javascript, java, url, browser, client-side

**The problem definition**

On my page, www.xxx.com/page, there is a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.1234.js"></script>
```

Browser relolves it as www.xxx.com/main.1234.js instead of www.xxx.com/page/main.1234.js

---

**More details about my setup**

In fact, there are two applications running on the same server machine:

- www.xxx.com/ (app #1)
- www.xxx.com:82/ (app #2)

The page actually exists in the app #2 as www.xxx.com:82/page. If I access the page directly, then everything works as it should work (i.e. browser resolves links as expected).

But my setup is a bit more complicated. My goal is to hide app #2 from any public access, and make it available only via app #1 as www.xxx.com/page. In order to achieve that, I setup app #1 so, that if a user requests www.xxx.com/page, then app #1 under the hood performs a request to www.xxx.com:82/page of app #2 and returns received content back to the user.

From user's point of view everything should look like content of www.xxx.com:82/page resides under www.xxx.com/page. And it almost works.  The only problem is that for some reason browser resolves URLs as I described under "The problem definition". **How to fix it?**

---

**Additional info, hope it may help**

I suppose, that an answer should be hidden in the responces. I suppose, that a cause is that the browser receives different response headers. The following are lists of headers the browser receives in each of these two cases:

1. Response from app #1 (www.xxx.com/page) where browser incorrectly resolves URLs:

> - Cache-Control:private
> - Content-Length:775
> - Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
> - Date:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 11:34:40 GMT
> - Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
> - Set-Cookie:zimidy-initialSessionIdHash=-226086716; Path=/
> - Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
> - X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
> - X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
> - X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

2. Response from app #2 (www.xxx.com:82/page) where browser correctly resolves URLs:

> - Accept-Ranges:bytes
> - Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
> - Connection:keep-alive
> - Date:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 11:33:16 GMT
> - ETag:W/"307-1610e1964c4"
> - Last-Modified:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 11:06:40 GMT
> - X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: Have you tried `src="/main.1234.js"></script>`?

Comment: The url is resolved correctly. Care about the trailing slash here: www.xxx.com/page -> www.xxx.com/page/

Comment: @RolandStarke Wow! Ending slash helps indeed! Never thought it does matter. Can you comment, why it matters and how it affects behaviour? If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The URL of

main.1234.js

starts from the location your page is in. The URL of

/main.1234.js

starts from the location of the baseurl. You have problably meant the baseurl. If your path is foo/bar/mypage, then linking main.1234.js will search for the file in foo/bar/. If you put a slash to the start, it will search for the file in the baseurl, which should be the root folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. But it works differently, which is why I asked the question. Actually, RolandStarke commented with an answer, that helped to fix the problem. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

RolandStarke gave me [an advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340754/browser-resolves-relative-urls-as-if-they-were-absolute/48342827#comment83666818_48340754), which helped me to solve the problem.

Also, an explanation of the behaviour can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445016/4829388).

---

To make relative URLs to work properly, ending slash is required. I used it in the link from app #2, but not in the link from app #1. After addition of ending slash, everything started to work.

- So, this link doesn't work properly: `www.xxx.com/app`
- But this one, with ending slash, does work as expected: `www.xxx.com/app/`