# Add "#" hash correctly to url with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit confused, because I just want to add a hash to an existing url via varibale and open it via `a href`.

Example:

```
$( ".MyLink" ).each( function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr("href", "https://website.com/subpage#" + href);
});
```

Result (browser url) after clicking on this link:

```
https://website.com/subpage/#test
```

If I am right, a correct hash link should look like this ...

```
https://website.com/subpage#test
```

... without the "/" after subpage.

So, I am correct or it doesn't matter? If yes, how can I change it?

I also realized that my browser(s) change my url from `https://website.com/subpage#test` to `https://website.com/subpage/#test` if I just add it in the browser bar and press enter. Is that new?

Maybe it is important to know that I use wordpress?

**OK, it seemes to be a php/browser/wordpress rule that `#` become `/#`, because this script creates an endless refresh-loop for me:**

```
var urlupdate = window.location.href.replace("/#", "#");
window.location.href = urlupdate;
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: [When should I use a trailing slash in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url)

Comment: Thx 4 the link, I will take a look ...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As described in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326600), it shouldn't make a difference if your Javascript was written properly, it seems to be even considered as a best practice. If you want to get rid of it anyways you may want to check your wordpress settings, maybe the second answer of the given question may give you a hint!

---

In case that the trailing slash comes from the `a` tag, you could check whether the string in the `href` attribute starts with a slash and remove it then:

```
$( ".MyLink" ).each( function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href.charAt(0) === '/') {
        href = href.substring(1, href.length);
    }

    $(this).attr("href", "https://website.com/subpage#" + href);
});
```

Comment: Thx 4 help. That would be a bit hacky, but it also doesnt work ;(

Comment: Could you add your HTML code also for further understanding, please? :)

Comment: I have updated my question - it seemes to be a php/browser/wordpress rule.