# .htaccess rewrite conditon after spesific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using apache2 and laravel so I put this code inside `.htaccess` on `/public` folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(blog|dont/you|brave-to|fvck|me)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

code above is working only if url spesific with the `/url`

An example `https://mywebsite.com/blog` or `https://mywebsite.com/dont/you`

so with this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]`
will redirect you to get `tailling slash`

so will be `https://mywebsite.com/blog/`

[image]

But when I want to add dynamic slug this not working
[image]
[link test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=0f62eae0-3b44-4a92-8c74-02d8ac97af9f)

I mean, I need to add tailling slash `after end of slug` following by `blog`
an example if the url like this `https://mywebsite.com/blog/hey-this-dynamic-slug`
this should be `https://mywebsite.com/blog/hey-this-dynamic-slug/`

I have to add this condition and rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(?:blog/)\S+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

yes sure working fine [image]

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=47516f5c-b5c6-49e9-87fa-3b83cec864fc

but this will force all with `/`
[image]

as you can see when I try to change `blog` with random text this rule force to add `/`

I just need to force add tailling slash only for spesific url and after spesific url

Comment: What does this have to do with `Laravel`? You should never modify the `.htaccess`, what are you using?

Comment: what do you mean? don't modify `.htaccess` ? @matiaslauriti

Comment: I am going to say it again, why do you need a trailing slash at the end of a url?

Comment: I am asking this because it is not something everyone needs, specially with Laravel, so you are either doing something wrong, or you have a good case, so please share the why, because we will learn either way... it is also on the [ask]... you need to share information...

Comment: For self site maybe this not important, but when you care about SEO or Web Structure you need to do this. I'm still thinking why when we use cms like wordpress/blog they give you option for how  `Permalinks` will appear on your site? They must not give this option if they dont take care about this. Also our community open threads [When Should I use a trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url) or [Why trailing slashes on URIs are important](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/)

Comment: 1. laravel have default .htacess and will remove `/` at the end (I'm done with this)
2. if you take care about route may you need to know if `Route::post('/testurl/')` with `Route::post('/testurl')` will have different effect. thats why I need to do this for only spesific url. like I say before the .htacess is working fine, but what I want is for spesific url  and after spesific url. this important for handling the route post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So i got it use this condition

```
RewriteEngine On
// check if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
// check if there start with blog/ and not end with /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blog/.*)[^/]$ [OR]
// OR check if contain specific words
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blog|dont/you|brave-to|fvck|me)$
// the do the rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

this an [example](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=6a1af3f9-6cf5-479c-b787-613cef591c11)

[image]