# how to make navigation work without starting with index.html in path?

Tags: html, apache, web, dom, server

I have an apache2 web server, located at `/var/www/html`. The endpoint is `xyz.com` and is university-afiliated and managed. The root of mine is supposedly `xyz.com/name` and it is proxied to by the main server.

When I have:

```
# index.html
link to href='other.html'
```

```
# other.html
link to href='./'
```

in `var/www/html`, this only works if the user starts at `xyz.com/name/index.html` (with the user correctly routed to `xyz.com/name/other.html`); otherwise, if the user starts at `xyz.com/name` then they get routed to `xyz.com/other.html` (which does not exist).

How can I fix this? (prefer HTML + server config only)

Comment: The issue isn't index.html, the issue is having `name` or `name/`. The forward slash is important for the directory structure.

Comment: I don’t want to burden the users with that @TimR

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises when you don't have a [trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url).

`xyz.com/name/` with a trailing slash is conventionally a directory
`xyz.com/name` without a trailing slash is conventionally a file

Relative links from `xyz.com/name` will resolve relative to the root directory `xyz.com/` because `name` is assumed to be a file within the root directory. This could break not only anchors but images and stylesheet links as well.

If `name` is a directory, some servers will automatically redirect to `name/`. Since yours doesn't, you could set it up to do so (either directly on the server via `httpd.conf` or via a `.htaccess` file in the root web directory.) This will prevent the aforementioned linking issues as well as prevent duplicate content from both URLs (an SEO concern.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

More information and explanation can be found in the article "[Should You Have a Trailing Slash at the End of URLs?](https://ahrefs.com/blog/trailing-slash/)" as well as by performing a web search for trailing slash in URL.

---

An alternative to redirecting is to use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) HTML element in the `<head>`, which specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs in a document.

Caution: this can break in-page anchors. Using `<base href="/name/">` on `xyz.com/name/other.html`, the link `<a href="#some-id">in-page anchor</a>` points to `xyz.com/name/#some-id`. However, it's not necessary to use `<base>` in every page, only in `index.html`.

Comment: I just tried the rules you specified at `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html` and it does not work. Same issue. I should add that `xyz.com/name` (no trailing slash) originally results in the same location as `xyz.com/name/`, which is `xyz.com/name/index.html`. It is only on attempted relative re-directions (say to `other.html`) that we then see `xyz.com/other.html`.

Comment: The `base` method on the other hand, after the second re-direction (back to `index.html` and to another page) sends you to `xyz.com/name/name/other.html`.

Comment: When updating the .htaccess, it's best to test changes after closing the browser, possibly hitting reload, or even better in a private window. Did you use `<base href="/name/">` with a leading and trailing slash? `/name/`

Comment: Tested in Safari and Chrome on incognito/private windows. I specified `base` exactly as you said. I want to emphasize it's only on the second re-direction where there is a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "second re-direction"? Are you saying that when you are on `xyz.com/name/other.html` and use the `href='./'` link, it correctly links to `xyz.com/name/` but then the `href='other.html'` link is linking to `xyz.com/name/name/other.html`?

Comment: I'm saying that if you start at `/name`, having put `base href='/name'` in `index.html`, then if you go to `other.html` back to `index.html` and back to `other.html`, then that second time you go to `other.html` will send you to `xyz.com/name/name/other.html`, while the first does so correctly.

Comment: You should not have `base href='/name'`. It needs to end with a slash. `<base href="/name/">`

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. It did end with a /.

Comment: I can't replicate that unless I leave out the first slash `<base href="name/">`

Comment: I am not sure then. Thanks a lot for trying to help. I just tested again and with `<base href='/name/>`, the issue persists.

Comment: Make sure you're not missing the closing quotation mark. ;-) Does it link to `xyz.com/name/name/other.html` even when you go directly to `xyz.com/name/` (not back and forth between pages)

Comment: I always seem to make typos when speaking to you lol. `xyz.com/name/` always works properly (even without `base`). `xyz.com/name` directs to `xyz.com/other.html` when you click `href='other.html'`. If you add `base`, the only behavior that changes is `xyz.com/name` directs to `xyz.com/name/other.html` the first time, but when you go back via `href='./'` and click the link again, it sends you to `xyz.com/name/name/other.html`. I hope that's clear.