# Using Cloudflare to add trailing slash to URL

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, cloudflare

The firm I work for recently launched a new site, but at the moment the URLs don't add a trailing slash automatically to those that don't have them - but the old site used to do this. This is causing a few broken links and SEO problems.

How do I use Cloudflare to add a trailing slash to URLs those that need them. For example:

`www.example.com/blog`

Automatically gets rewritten to:

```
www.example.com/blog/
```

But I don't want to do this for any other URLs that end with a parameter such as:

```
www.example.com/blog?campaign_URL=mycampaignparam
```

Or files such as:

`www.example.com/css/stylesheet.css`

I've tried using the transform rules in Cloudflare like so, but it ended up breaking the pages completely and I'm not sure why:

[image: Cloudflare transform rule attempt]

I've not had to use Cloudflare transform rules before and stuff like Regex and concat is my Kryptonite so I'm hoping someone has some guidance.

EDIT: Also, this site has two areas - sales and blog - which are on two separate servers and content management system, so I can't just implement a solution on a single origin server.

Comment: Why wouldn't you implement this on your origin server?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - because this website has two sides to it - a sales side and a blog side - which are on separate servers and CMS but have been brought together under a single domain by Cloudflare, so it's not as cut as dry as a "single origin server". I also have no control over the origin server for the sales side of the site. So I need a solution that can cover both sides of the site.

Comment: If you don't have control over the origin, you probably shouldn't be adding slashes to the URLs.  That can cause links to resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) to break.  URLs are usually better without the trailing slash anyway.  See [When should I use a trailing slash in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url)

Comment: Bringing separate servers together under one domain is usually handled by subdomains rather than by complicated rules in a CDN.  It sounds to me like you are pursuing a solution that is going to lock you into a specific CDN vendor and not give you the flexibility you need to choose the best hosting in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to use a plug for the Wordpress side, Permalink Manager, to manage the trailing slash. Normally this wouldn't be such a pain to manage, but due to how this particular site was set up this was the best way to get the trailing slash to do what I needed to do.